# .... I was being! / what does it mean?

Tags: word-usage, auxiliary-verbs, past-simple, past-continuous

> I could hardly believe how bold I was *being*!
>
> I got detention because a teacher said I was *being* contumacious

.....
What does the word *being* here mean ? and what are the *tenses* in these sentences ?

Why we can not just omit it ?

And just say:

I could hardly believe how bold I was!

I got detention because a teacher said I was contumacious.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When *BE* is cast in the **progressive construction** (*BE* + present participle), it describes the subject's current behavior, as opposed to his more or less permanent nature or character:

> I was being bold *means I was behaving boldly at that time*.
>   I was being contumacious *means I was behaving contumaciously at that time.*